# What's the most efficient way to conditionally join two tables with random result order

Tags: mysql

The problem is very similar to the stack exchange voting system. I'd like to query an object table for a random object and also get back any votes a specified user has on that object.

```
objects table:
 id
 user_id
 message

votes table:
 object_id
 user_id
 vote_value
```

`select * from objects order by RAND()` produces a random object, but how can I select a specific user's vote value for that object in the same query? It's possible that the user never votes on the result object so I can't simply do a join on id/object_id.

Comment: What should the output be if the user didn't vote on an object?

Comment: it should just be the object's id and message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will print `NULL` for `user_id` and `vote_value` if the user (in this case `1`) didn't vote on an object:

```
SELECT o.id, v.user_id, v.vote_value 
FROM objects o LEFT OUTER JOIN votes v ON o.id = v.object_id AND v.user_id = 1
WHERE v.user_id = 1 OR v.user_id IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: You could also use `IFNULL()` to print whatever you want in place of the `NULL`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull